# The vue-router do not get the correct param

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This is the url link:

```
http://localhost:8080/home/workpanel/?CFR=2f19f86ff8be446f
```

I use the `router-link` push to there:

```
<router-link
  :to="{path: '/home/workpanel', query: {CFR:2f19f86ff8be446f }}"
>
</router-link>
```

But, however, in that url page, I get nothing of the `route.params`, I `console.log` in the console of Chrome:

```
this.$route.params 
{}
```

There is no `CFR`, someone can tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check into *this.$route.query* because you passed a query params